# Does Updatable Resultset and Recordset exist in Firebird .NET Provider?

Tags: database, vb.net, firebird, resultset, recordset

I tried Firebird with .NET Provider yesterday. Firebird was sure to beat SQL Compact Edition. I was amazed from it's features and precision. But I felt sad when I wasn't able to find updatable RecordSet/ResultSet features and functions in the .NET provider. FBResultSet doesn't contains anything, no rows addition, creation, modification, nothing. Anybody knows if this feature exists in Ado .Net provider of Firebird because there's no documentation. I would like to receive help because I am waiting to integrate Firebird in my freeware application. Also, if there's are replacement functions for implementing updatable RecordSet, ResultSet. Please help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I've been there, done that, and got the t-shirt. So, as I felt your pain I will give you some code that should help you.

I used stored procedures (sprocs) to do any record update addtion, etc. Then I wrote a class wrapper to call the sprocs.

enter code here

So, with this code for the sproc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_IU_BATCH (
    AUTYPE INTEGER,
    BATCHID INTEGER,
    MAT_BATCHID INTEGER,
    DOS DATE,
    FACILITYID INTEGER)
RETURNS (
    RTNIDX INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (:AUTYPE = 0) THEN
    BEGIN
        FOR
            SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_BATCH_ID,1)
            FROM RDB$DATABASE
        INTO
            :RTNIDX
        DO
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO BATCH (BATCHID, MAT_BATCHID, DOS, FACILITYID)
            VALUES (:RTNIDX, :MAT_BATCHID, :DOS, :FACILITYID);
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE BATCH SET MAT_BATCHID=COALESCE(:MAT_BATCHID, MAT_BATCHID), DOS=COALESCE(:DOS, DOS),
        FACILITYID=COALESCE(:FACILITYID, FACILITYID)
        WHERE BATCHID=:BATCHID;
    END
END
```

You would access it with this database wrapper: myfbdb.vb

```
    Imports FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird
Imports FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird.Services
Imports FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird.Isql
Imports System.IO

Public Class myfbdb

#Region " Private Variables "
    Private dbConn As FbConnection = Nothing, dbBatch As Batch = Nothing
    Private Const dbName As String = "yourdatabasename.fdb", dbUser As String = "SYSDBA", dbPass As String = "yourpassword"
#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "
    Private Sub Connect()
        If dbConn Is Nothing Then
            Try
                dbConn = New FbConnection(GetConnString)
            Catch ex As FbException
                RaiseError(ex)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Initialize()
        dbBatch = New Batch
        dbBatch.dbConn = Me
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " Private Functions "
    Private Function GetConnString() As String
        Dim rtnString As String = Nothing
        Dim fbCSB As New FbConnectionStringBuilder
        fbCSB.Database = dbName
        fbCSB.Password = dbPass
        fbCSB.UserID = dbUser
        fbCSB.ServerType = 1
        rtnString = fbCSB.ToString
        fbCSB = Nothing
        Return rtnString
    End Function
#End Region

#Region " Public Properties "
    Public ReadOnly Property cmdb() As FbConnection
        Get
            Return dbConn
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property cmBatch() As Batch
        Get
            Return dbBatch
        End Get
    End Property
    End Property
#End Region

#Region " Public Methods "

#Region " New "
    Public Sub New()
        Connect()
        Initialize()
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " Finalize "
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        MyBase.Finalize()
        Close()
        Unload()
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " Unload "
    Public Sub Unload()
        If Not dbConn Is Nothing Then
            If dbConn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                dbConn.Close()
            End If
            dbConn = Nothing
        End If
        UnInitialize()
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " Open / Close "
    Public Sub Open()
        Try
            If Not dbConn Is Nothing Then
                If dbConn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                    dbConn.Close()
                End If
                dbConn.Open()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            RaiseError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()
        If Not dbConn Is Nothing Then
            dbConn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

#End Region

End Class
```

And here is the Batch Wrapper for the Sproc:

```
    Imports FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird
Imports FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird.Services
Imports FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird.Isql

Public Class Batch

#Region " Private Variables "
    Private clsCM As myfbdb
#End Region

#Region " Private Enums "
    Private Enum AUType
        Add = 0
        Update = 1
    End Enum
#End Region

#Region " Stored Procedures "

#Region " Add / Update "
    Private Function AU_Batch(ByVal itmBatch As cmdbType_Batch, ByVal au As AUType) As Integer
        Try
            Dim rtnIndex As Integer = -1
            'Create Temporary Command
            Dim tmpTrans As FbTransaction = clsCM.cmdb.BeginTransaction
            Dim tmpSQLCommand As FbCommand = New FbCommand("SP_IU_BATCH", clsCM.cmdb, tmpTrans)
            tmpSQLCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

            'Add Parameters
            Dim prmAUType As FbParameter = tmpSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@AUTYPE", FbDbType.Integer)
            Dim prmBatchID As FbParameter = tmpSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@BATCHID", FbDbType.Integer)
            Dim prmMAT_BatchID As FbParameter = tmpSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@MAT_BATCHID", FbDbType.Integer)
            Dim prmDOS As FbParameter = tmpSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@DOS", FbDbType.Date)
            Dim prmFacilityName As FbParameter = tmpSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@FACILITYNAME", FbDbType.VarChar, 250)
            Dim prmFacilityID As FbParameter = tmpSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@FACILITYID", FbDbType.Integer)
            Dim prmRtnIdx As FbParameter = tmpSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@RTNIDX", FbDbType.Integer)
            'Specify Output Parameters
            prmRtnIdx.Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.Output
            'Set the Parameter Values
            With itmBatch
                prmAUType.Value = CInt(au)
                prmBatchID.Value = .BatchID
                prmMAT_BatchID.Value = .MAT_BatchID
                prmDOS.Value = .DOS
                prmFacilityName.Value = clsCM.enc.EncryptString128Bit(.FacilityName, Crypt_Text(clsCM.ivKey))
                prmFacilityID.Value = .FacilityID
            End With

            'Execute the Stored Procedure
            tmpSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If au = AUType.Add Then
                rtnIndex = prmRtnIdx.Value
            End If

            tmpTrans.Commit()

            'Clean up
            tmpSQLCommand = Nothing
            Return rtnIndex
        Catch ex As Exception
            RaiseError(ex)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
#End Region

#Region " Public Functions "
    Public Function AddBatch(ByVal itmBatch As cmdbType_Batch) As Integer
        Try
            clsCM.Open()
            Dim rtnInteger As Integer = AU_Batch(itmBatch, AUType.Add)
            clsCM.Close()
            Return rtnInteger
        Catch ex As Exception
            RaiseError(ex)
            clsCM.Close()
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function UpdateBatch(ByVal itmBatch As cmdbType_Batch) As Integer
        Try
            clsCM.Open()
            Dim rtnInteger As Integer = AU_Batch(itmBatch, AUType.Update)
            clsCM.Close()
            Return rtnInteger
        Catch ex As Exception
            RaiseError(ex)
            clsCM.Close()
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
#End Region

#Region " Public Properties "
    Public WriteOnly Property dbConn() As CodingModuleDB
        Set(ByVal value As CodingModuleDB)
            clsCM = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region

End Class
```

That was a lot of code, but I had to do this the hard way and it stunk. I hope you can use this to bridge your gap to get up and running. Firebird really is a great database.

Comment: Thanks for the source code. I do not know what to put where, and how to call a specific function to update any row from the DataTable.